# how to align a photoshop layer or part of it with the guide line or the document center

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, alignment, actions, guides

how to align the whole layer by referencing it to a specific area in that layer, the way the whole layer moves to the center of the document or to be centered in a specific guideline.

this problem have two branches the first one is how to align any layer with any single guideline in the document? and the seconf banch is how to align any selected area in the layer to the center of the document?

I was trying to make an action that when I click in specific point in an layer i could align that point to the center of the document.
how do I do that?!

to be more clear
the the photo hereunder I need to pick a point in the center of the red circle (or any picked ppoint) so that point i picked become the center of the document and/or the center on any given guideline. the way that I could do that in a batch mode.
click and center the document.

[image]

or

for the hereunder screenshot ... how can I move both layes the balck circle layer (layer1) and the layer below it (layer 0) to be centered based on the circle layer as a refrence
ps. linking layer dosent work!

[image]

Comment: Hi. Not sure I understand the problem you are trying to solve here. Can't you just click and drag any point on the image to the centre? [see example](https://imgur.com/79Re1Up)

Comment: @BillyKerr for sure it is simple to drag at any point ... but if we are talking about thouthads of images the drag will not be an easy task. waht i dream of is a simple action so that all what I do is clicking without thinking to match. or mabe I am asking for a new feature or some sort of script.

Comment: if i simplify my requirment ... is it possible to link two layes and align one layer that have the pointer refrence and the linked layer move to the new posion accordingly !?

Comment: I understand what you mean. However, it's hard to automate framing/centring like this if a decision has to be made for each image.  Photoshop has no brain, it's just a dumb machine. At most you could simply crop all images to the exact same, but that might not be any good for you if the images are all different.

Comment: It might be worthwhile looking at Adobe Lightroom for processing photos like this.  Quick manual cropping and framing is possible without the need to save images in between each edit. Then once you have finished you can export them all in one batch.

Comment: If all the images are the same subject/scene, it might be possible to auto align images using Photoshop's Auto Align functionality. There's [a tutorial here:](https://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-editing/how-to-auto-align-and-composite-images-in-photoshop/#:~:text=With%20both%20layers%20selected%2C%20go%20up%20to%20the,so%20we%27ll%20let%20it%20do%20all%20the%20work.)

Comment: @BillyKerr, to reformlse m problem in simple words. how to pick any part f th image to be aligned in the center?! ... pick and auto align, pick and move the image to be the picke poiint in the cener of the document.